# Why does `std::chrono::weekday` allow but doesn't preserve values outside of valid range?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, c++20

According to section [[time.cal.wd.overview]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.cal.wd) of the C++ standard:

> `weekday` represents a day of the week in the civil calendar. It normally holds values in the range `0` to `6`, corresponding to Sunday through Saturday, but it may hold non-negative values outside this range.

At the same time arithmetic operations perform modulo 7 arithmetic forcing the result in the range `[0, 6]`, e.g.

```
weekday wd(7);
// wd.ok() == false - wd is invalid
++wd; // wd == weekday(1)
// wd.ok() == true  - wd silently becomes valid
```

Why does `weekday` have such peculiar behavior, particularly why are values outside of `[0, 6]` allowed but not preserved by arithmetic operations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `weekday(unsigned wd)` constructor promises to hold any value in the range [0, 255].  The rationale for this is:

1. It's very fast.
2. It allows a client to assign an "unused" value to something useful in the client's logic.

For an example of (2):

```
constexpr weekday not_a_weekday{255};
...
weekday wd = not_a_weekday;
in >> wd;
if (wd == not_a_weekday)
    throw "oops";
```

---

`weekday` arithmetic forces the range back into [0, 6] because if you write the algorithm to do modulo 7 arithmetic, with no range checking at all, this is what naturally happens.  I.e. this is the fastest thing to do.

---

So in summary:  Performance is the rationale for the current `weekday` spec, combined with a `sizeof` which is as small as possible (which can also contribute to performance).

However given as much performance as possible, whatever behaviors are left over (occur naturally) can be beneficial to standardize and let clients take advantage of these behaviors as opposed to saying that they are Undefined Behavior <sup>TM</sup>.

Indeed, the spec avoids UB as much as possible, opting for Unspecified Behavior instead.  For example `weekday{300}` may not store the value you want, but it *can not* reformat your disk, and the optimizer is not allowed to pretend the code doesn't exist.

Comment: Performance considerations make sense although I have mixed feelings about invalid weekdays becoming valid after some operations and the inability for implementations to introduce debug checks.

Comment: Here's a fun way to force a `weekday` into a valid range: `wd += days{0};`

Comment: The spec allows clients to introduce debug checks at a higher level, where it makes sense in the client's logic.  And sometimes a `!ok()` values is not an error in the client's logic.  For example: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#not_ok_is_ok

Answer (score 4):

> Why does weekday have such peculiar behavior, particularly why are values outside of `[0, 6]` allowed but not preserved by arithmetic operations?

Any arithmetic operation on `weekday` will potentially overflow. So you *have* to do a modulo operation there. It's important that `sat + days{1} == sun`, since that's what everyone expects. And you really want `(sat + days{1}).ok()` to hold as well, since surely that's valid. And it's just as important that `sat + days{8} == sun` and `sat + days{701} == sun`, and so forth. That's just how calendar arithmetic works.

So it's pretty necessary to do a modulo 7 on all the arithmetic operations. There's just no point in holding `8` as a weekday value - that's not really a valid weekday.

On the other hand, doing the modulo on construction doesn't have as much clear value. It's extra work that you may not need to do, and it might even hide bugs. What if you want to just validate `weekday(user_input).ok()`? Would everyone that needs to know what to check externally?

In short, values above `6` are allowed on construction because that makes sense to allow, but arithmetic doesn't preserve them because it doesn't make sense to preserve them.

But Howard is a frequent contributor to SO, so he'll probably chime in with a [better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54042239/2069064).

Comment: The modulo operations make perfect sense to me but the wording forbidding checks for invalid values seems weird.

Comment: Also the fact that the invalid value silently becomes valid after an operation is a bit of a footgun.

Comment: @Caleth No, `sat + days{8}` absolutely must equal `sun`.

Comment: Ah, i'm mistaking `days` for `day` (similarly `weekday`). The current standard only requires `day` and `weekday` to be specified if supplied in the range `[0, 255]`

Comment: "it doesn't make sense to preserve them"


This I strongly disagree with. It makes sense to preserve them for the same reasons it makes sense to preserve NaNs. They represent invalid values (`ok() == false`). We might want not to preserve them for performance reasons, but that's a tradeoff between correctness and performance.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so strange.

If you give it an out-of-range value, then that is your mistake. It would not be fair to force us all to endure endless bounds checking just to catch this rare occurrence.

Similarly, it is not fair to expect the well-defined operations of this type to do anything in particular on values that are expressly considered out of range, nor is it immediately clear what sort of deterministic result you expect from such an operation. Which day comes after "ooglebooglebargleday"?

You'll find this philosophy a lot throughout C++. You don't pay for what you don't use, and you can shoot yourself in the foot as long as you don't mind having to carry yourself the rest of the way home.

Comment: Why doesn't weekday have an invariant that it stores a value in `[0, 6]`? It would be a single check (possibly debug-only) in one constructor, not everywhere. Instead it explicitly allows storing invalid values which looks strange.

Comment: @vitaut I would not be outrageously surprised to see such a check in debug, but that's an implementation issue. Here the contract is clearly stated (your categorisation of this as "explicitly allows storing invalid values" seems not to be a fair statement) and if the programmer breaks it that's the programmer's fault. There are hundreds of other such cases throughout C++ as I'm sure you know. What alternative behaviour are you expecting? An exception, or?

Comment: The standard seems to forbid such check by explicit wording that invalid values are allowed. That's what strikes me most. Maybe I'm just misunderstanding "may".

Comment: @vitaut I don't think so. Para 1 says _"It can be constructed with any unsigned value, which will be subsequently truncated to fit into weekday’s unspecified internal storage."_ So you can give it whatever value you like, and if you do you _may_ see some out-of-range value, or you may not, and an implementation can constrain this to its heart's content. Again, pretty usual for C++. Consider what happens when you overflow a signed integer.

Comment: @vitaut Tell you what though I do agree that overall the semantics in this section are not C++'s best. e.g. [time.cal.wd.members]/1 specifically names the range [0,255] because unsigned char is involved in the synopsis. It _is_ a bit leaky. I would caution you to remember that this _isn't_ the standard, it is a new feature in a working draft, and it is subject to change, and subject to suggestions ... and you could get on the mailing list and talk about improving it ;)

Comment: (Will probably integrate some of these thoughts into the answer in a bit)